# Calling realm from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, realm

Is there any way to call Realm queries from AsyncTask? 
I have so many queries that are doing join, So i want to call them from a separate **One** AsyncTask to avoid the load on UI Thread. For now i am using DefaultInstance of Realm everywhere. I get this error

> Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created

**P.S** I know Realm has its own Async for every query, but as i just mentioned i have alot of separate calls that are further doing joins and for loops.

**EDIT**

here's my code for an Async

```
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        //Step 1: Find All quote_taxes
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        listTaxData = new ArrayList<TaxData>();
        try {
            RealmResults<quote_taxes> listQuoteTaxes = quote_taxes.get_from_quotes(realm, quote.getId());
            if (listQuoteTaxes != null && listQuoteTaxes.size() > 0) {
                for (quote_taxes quoteTax : listQuoteTaxes) {
                    TaxData taxData = new TaxData();
                    taxData.setTaxName(quoteTax.getTaxName());
                    taxData.setAccountNumber("" + quoteTax.getAccountNumber());
                    taxData.setTaxRate("" + quoteTax.getTaxRate() + "%");
                    double total = quote_taxes.total(realm, quoteTax);
                    showLog("Total = " + total);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }finally {
            realm.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Some sample code...  https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/threadExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/threads/AsyncTaskFragment.java

Comment: Thank you..!
So that's the key, I need to fetch DefaultInstance inside doinBackground ?

Comment: Can't answer that. Never used Realm. Just really good at using Google for people

Comment: LOL!!! . Yeah, you are good. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just [have to do what the docs say](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances):

> For AsyncTask this is a good pattern:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        // ... Use the Realm instance ...
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

More importantly, you can use `try-with-resources`:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        // ... Use the Realm instance ...
    }

    return null;
}
```

> If you are using Thread or Runnable for short-lived tasks, the follow pattern is recommended:

```
// Run a non-Looper thread with a Realm instance.
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            // ... Use the Realm instance ...
        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

And use a `RealmChangeListener` on the UI thread to be notified of successful transactions in background threads.

---

---

**EDIT:** Oh, you want to perform asynchronous queries.

> I have so many queries that are doing join, So i want to call them from a separate One AsyncTask to avoid the load on UI Thread.

...while I truly doubt you have any "join"s considering Realm is not a relational database and the concept of `join`s doesn't exist in Realm; if you want *asynchronous queries*, you shouldn't overcomplicate your design with nonsense like `AsyncTask`. Just use [the asynchronous query methods](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries).

```
RealmResults<Something> results;
RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Object element) {
        if(results != null && results.isValid() && results.isLoaded()) {
            updateUI(results);
        }
    }
};

//...

results = realm.where(Something.class)./*...*/.findAllAsync(); // <-- async query
results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
```

Comment: I am sorry, i am getting an exception when i tried to implement this solution after few days. It says "Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created" 

In Application class this is how to realm is initialized first time: 
 realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);

And then in Async,I am getting the default instance: 
Any help ?

Comment: I cannot answer this without the actual code that throws this exception.

Comment: `quote.getId()` the `quote` belongs to a Realm that is on another thread, you should pass the ID to the background thread

Answer (score 3):

Realm has its Async load default functionality :-

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                   // Use the Realm instance
                     }
            });
```

Above execution done on background thread, and it's gives callback when db changes like.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // success callback 
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                // error callback 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you create Realm objects in `doInBackground` and then process results in `onPostExecute`? To avoid this you can use `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask`. If you still want to use `AsyncTask`, you can process query results in `doInBackground`as well and then return needed data (Lists, POJOs etc.) to `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Ahh, Yeah i guess that's what i was missing. Let me try a sample and i can mark this answer as accepted.